# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: appium, appium-android

I installed appium-doctor `npm install -g appium-doctor`.
I then tried to run `appium-doctor --android` to see any missing dependencies for android.
However, I got this error

```
.....\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v13.2.0\node_modules\appium-doctor\node_modules\uuid\dist\esm-browser\index.js:1
export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
^^^^^^
```

From googling it's an issue with nodeJS using CommonJS instead of ES6 syntax, but I don't know how to solve this error on my command line.

Comment: i also have this issue. something in the angular.json?

Answer (score 5):

[No valid exports main found for node_modules\uuid #5381](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5381)

> Node.js 13.5.0 seems to be broken. I tried 13.14.0 and 14.2.0. Both of
> them work.
> Please note you should use Node.js even versions for production. We
> support Node 10, 12, and 14.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the exact same error when I installed apollo-server. Node 14.5 solved it as Samuel mentioned.